# MVC 4 Multi Language Localization method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, multilingual

**Localization in ASP.NET MVC using vb.net I can not run my project.**

```
Public Class LocalizationWebFormViewEngine
    Inherits WebFormViewEngine
    Protected Overrides Function CreateView(controllerContext As ControllerContext, viewPath As String, masterPath As String) As IView
        Return New LocalizationWebFormView(viewPath, masterPath)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function CreatePartialView(controllerContext As ControllerContext, partialPath As String) As IView
        Return New LocalizationWebFormView(partialPath, Nothing)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class LocalizationWebFormView
    Inherits WebFormView
    Friend Const ViewPathKey As String = "__ViewPath__"

    **Public Sub New(viewPath As String)
        MyBase.New(viewPath)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(viewPath As String, masterPath As String)
        MyBase.New(viewPath, masterPath)
    End Sub**

    Public Overrides Sub Render(viewContext As ViewContext, writer As TextWriter)
        ' there seems to be a bug with RenderPartial tainting the page's view data
        ' so we should capture the current view path, and revert back after rendering
        Dim originalViewPath As String = DirectCast(viewContext.ViewData(ViewPathKey), String)

        viewContext.ViewData(ViewPathKey) = ViewPath
        MyBase.Render(viewContext, writer)

        viewContext.ViewData(ViewPathKey) = originalViewPath
    End Sub
End Class
```

3 gives the error.

1.**overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments**

```
Public Sub New (viewpath As String) 
    MyBase.New (viewpath) 
End Sub
```

**2.value can not be converted to the type of system.web.mvc.controllercontext**

```
Public Sub New (viewpath As String, String masterpath) 
    MyBase.New (viewpath, masterpath) 
End Sub
```

**3.Public override sub render (as ViewContext as system.web.mvc.viewcontext TextWriter writer can not override 'Public sub render' is not declared because overridable**

Solution: replace with shadows override

Public Overrides Sub Render (ViewContext ViewContext Ace, Ace TextWriter writer)

How do I fix errors related to vb.net side.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add markers to your code where the error messages are actually caused?

Comment: I get the error message at the bottom showed 3.